# jQuery file download + Receive csv

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig, silex

I'm trying to create an excel file with the jquery library [jquery file download](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/). This is what I have now:

```
var data = {{ tableresults|json_encode|raw }};

$('#exporttocsv').click(function(){
    $.fileDownload('dashboard/exporttocsv/' + data, {
        successCallback: function (url) {

            alert('You just got a file download dialog or ribbon for this URL :' + url);
        },
        failCallback: function (html, url) {

            alert('Your file download just failed for this URL:' + url + '\r\n' +
                    'Here was the resulting error HTML: \r\n' + html
            );
        }
    });
});
```

In my function I have this:

```
public function exporttocsvAction(Application $app, Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->get('data');

    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");

    foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($output, $row, ',');
    }

    fclose($output);
    exit();
}
```

But when I dump my $data variable in my function I just get a string like this:

> string(271) "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

How can I make sure that I get an array in my php function? I've also tried {{ tableresults }} without json_encode and raw but that gave a syntax error:

```
var data = <br />
```

**UPDATE:**

this a dump of the array I send to my view: http://pastebin.com/Y58aLqBX

Comment: Are you using Symfony?

Comment: I'm using Silex. A miro framework based on Symfony

Comment: Though, I think you need to create a response with the specific headers you mentioned and return the response; in your current code you are not returning anything to the browser

Comment: and why not using `get_file_content` instead of `fopen` [http://ca3.php.net/function.file-get-contents]

Comment: That's not the problem for now. The problem is that I don't get my data array correctly in my function. I just get a  string.

Comment: could you provide the code for action function which you produce `tableresults` and pass it to the template?

Comment: I added a dump of my array that I send to the view to my topic.

Comment: Base on the plugin documentation: you set the returned array to filedownload url (which is not correct) `$.fileDownload('dashboard/exporttocsv/' + data ...` it should be a url to the csv file which you want to download. The plugin uses ajax to the provided link and parse the returned response (which is the file content). I think if you change that to the file url it should be fixed. This the documentation linke [http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/]